# Installing podman on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: centos, amazon-linux-2, podman

I am trying to install podman on an Amazon Linux 2 instance

```
cat /etc/os-release

NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

These are the steps:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo curl -L -o /etc/yum.repos.d/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable.repo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/CentOS_7/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable.repo
sudo yum install yum-plugin-copr
sudo yum copr enable lsm5/container-selinux
sudo yum install podman
```

For the install command I get:

> No package podman available.

Any suggestions? I expect it would be pulled from here: https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable/podman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8888 appears to be very germane as another user from January 2021 had the same problem.

This repository may work instead, but the podman version is much older: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable:/old_podman/CentOS_7/

That OpenSuse build output shows that Centos 7 builds are disabled, and https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/CentOS_7/ shows no podman rpms in any of it's subdirectories. It looks like the podman install instructions used to contain the steps you mention, but  Amazon Linux 2 installation documentation was removed by this [commit](https://github.com/containers/podman.io/commit/89c603e9c8a80716ddd6a0baa9039da38582a6f5) which refers to this blog post:
https://podman.io/blogs/2021/03/02/podman-support-for-older-distros.html

For support of fast-moving projects, it's usually best to use as modern an OS as you can support. RHEL8 seems to work well for me.